# Why is there a drastic difference in search time between lucenenet in c# and lucene in java while the other statistics are roughly comparable?

Tags: java, c#, lucene, lucene.net

I have implemented a Lucene POC in Java and dotnet. The stats are roughly comparable except for the search time(time required to get the matching docs). **Java application roughly takes 9-10 seconds whereas Dotnet took 52 minutes.** I have indexed 99000 documents which comprise of pdf,docs,txt and etc. Indexing for both of the POCs were performed on the same files. Is this disparity in search time expected due to the java version being superior or is there some error in my coding for lucenedotnet ?

Comment: "*Why is there a drastic difference in search time between blah language and blah langauge?** - simply, they are not the same language, likely optimized differently, written by who knows in whos knows what way

Comment: Orders of magnitude difference is not attributable to simply different languages. There's something else that's different.

Comment: Sounds like there's some error to me.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask here https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues

Comment: Simplest explanation would be that Lucene.Net is buggy, the latest version is still in Beta. Since it is a port of the Java version it should not be chocking if it is less mature and that it might have some performance problems. You could also do some profiling to ensure your own code is not at fault.

Answer (score 0):

This questions was also submitted as an issue to the lucene.NET repository.  For documentation here on StackOverflow about the performance of Lucene.NET 4.8 Beta, I will quote the response of one developer, jeme:

> This certainly sounds oversuspicious, we have an index with over a million documents, each with thousands of fields.
> If i do a free text search (meaning it accesses all fields) starting and ending with a wildcard (eg. *a*), which is probably the worst case scenario I can think of, it takes merely ~50 seconds, that is including loading the actual 9 megabytes of data the search produces and returning it over the wire. (not completely satisfying, but considering the punishment I just directed at the index + wire, it's somewhat understandable)...

Upon further research, the issue was experienced while utilizing version 3.03 of Lucene.NET rather then 4.8 Beta.  It is unclear whether the performance issue cited by this developer relates to the Lucene.NET 3.03 source code or project specific implementation source code.

You can read more here: https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues/333#issuecomment-685039718